# How do I create a WCF Service Library project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2017, project-template

I need to develop an application for my distributed computing class, with one central server and multiple graphical clients. I was thinking of trying WCF for this, since I am already familiar with making .NET standalone desktop applications using Windows Forms or WPF.

Since I have never worked with WCF before, I am trying to follow a tutorial posted on MSDN, which has [defining a service contract as its first major step](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731835(v=vs.110).aspx).* Part of this involves creating a **WCF Service Library** project, which is supposed to be available as a template under the language of my choice (I am going to use C# here). However, I do not see this project template listed as an option in the new project dialog, and looking for WCF in the search bar returns no results.

How can I make this project template available for use in Visual Studio 2017?

* *<sub>It should probably be noted that the tutorial mentions that it is written with Visual Studio 2012 in mind. Has anything changed since then that I should be aware of as far as the tutorial is concerned?</sub>*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Open the installer, choose Individual Components and scroll down to Development Activities. Check the WCF checkbox:

[image: WCF checkbox in the Visual Studio installer]

Comment: I had to uninstall the 'Windows communication Foundation' activity and then reinstall it fot the templates to show up.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up re-running the Visual Studio Installer to modify my current setup. WCF is not explicitly listed anywhere, but I figured it might have been included as part of the .NET Core or ASP.NET workloads (which were not marked for installation the first time around). After adding these workloads to my installation and restarting Visual Studio 2017, I can now see the WCF project templates listed under C#.